# How to retrieve keys in large REDIS databases using SCAN

Tags: redis

I have a large redis database where I query keys using `SCAN` using the syntax:

```
SCAN 0 MATCH *something* COUNT 50
```

I get the result

```
 1) "500000"
 2) (empty list or set)
```

but the key is there. If I call subsequent with the new key in 1) at some time I will get the result.

I was under the impression `MATCH` would return matching keys until the max number specified by `COUNT`, but it seems REDIS scans `COUNT` keys and return only if they match.

Do I miss something? How can I do: "give me the first (count) keys that match the match" ?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/36918471/3160475

Comment: You are right, duplicate