# How to Retrieve Keys in Redis

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

Currently I am working on writing a caching system using Redis.  Initially, I was storing a dictionary of  as the value, and a combination of dates as the key.  This worked great, but I was concerned about eventually hitting the size limit for the value.  I tried using HashEntries, but it was incredibly inefficient.  Now, I am trying storing each MyClass object separately, using a the original key with a the ID appended to it.  However, when I am doing the retrieval from the cache, I need to be able to retrieve values where the key contains the date substring.  I read that using Keys() is very slow which defeats the purpose of the cache.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918471/redis-scan-returns-empty-results-but-nonzero-cursor) about using scan and cursors, but couldn't get the keys from the RedisResult.

I was hoping that somebody either could help me with the scan, show me a way to get the keys that doesn't hurt performance, or another idea for caching large lists of data.

Comment: How large is large? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti For what I am testing it is only like 20 MegaBytes.  However, depending on what data the user is trying to cache the size could potentially reach the 512 MB limit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, scanning caches is not something that would increase perfomance of application.

What would be suggested is to re-structure your cache to be able to address a single record by date.

Could Redis lists or sets be an option for you?

Comment: From what I've tested just storing the Dictionary as a string seems to be the fastest.  Decided to just compress it before insertion as this both will decrease the size and speeds up the retrieval.  Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Great! Good for you @Kess!